# Is it possible to change the Wordpress parameter "/page/2" to something else?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, php-5.3

> **Disclaimer**: I'm working on a legacy corporate WP site (PHP 5.3.3), and I can't make very many major breaking changes.

I am adding pagination to an existing resources page (/resources). I'm fairly new to Wordpress in general, but I do have my page working and displaying the correct number of resources on page load.

My question is: when you paginate in Wordpress using:

```
<?php next_posts_link( 'More Resources' , $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
```

It creates a link on the page, and when you click it, WP automagically adds the page param like so: **/resources/page/2/**. The issue I'm having is that I get a 404 the minute I click it. I've done a ton of reading on this, and the main reason this happens usually is when you make a custom query using wp_query, and the number of posts in the custom query differs from the one in the main page query. I thought this was the issue originally, so I moved the logic to set the posts_per_page param into a **pre_post_load** hook, and this is functioning fine:

```
function exp_wp_modify_main_query ( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_page( 'resources' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) { // Run only on resources page
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 8;
    }

}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exp_wp_modify_main_query' );
```

I do have enough blog posts to require pagination (there are more posts than my number of posts per page). I believe the issue is related to the fact that this page is set up without categories. The resources page doesn't have categories. So instead of the url looking like this:
**resources/some_category/page/2/**, it's just resources/page/2. Is it possible that WP thinks "pages" is the category and that's why it's throwing a 404?

If yes, is there a way to change **/pages/2/** to **/p/2/**, and if yes to that, is that even a good idea?

Comment: Update, I found out how to change the pagination base (add_action( 'init', 'ds_set_pagination_base' ))!

But it's still broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. To change the pagination base:

I made this function in my plugin:

```
function set_pagination_base () {

    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = 'p';

}
```

And then:

```
add_action( 'init', 'set_pagination_base' );
```

Comment: Can we apply this for specific taxonomies?