# wordpress theme development, custom pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I want to rename the URL of WordPress pages page number. Currently it is : 
http://yourdomain.com/page/3

I want it to be :
http://yourdomain.com/newtext/3

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to change the Wordpress parameter "/page/2" to something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979496/is-it-possible-to-change-the-wordpress-parameter-page-2-to-something-else)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your admin dashboard, go to `settings` > `permalink`, select custom structure, then in the text field: `/%postname%/%post_id%/`

Comment: This is not the correct answer, a single page (as a post type) can have multiple sub-pages (numbered). So suggesting `/postname/post_id` is completely irrelevant.